# Why doesn't Jadzia appear in DS9's final montage?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, behind-the-scenes

The series finale of *Deep Space Nine*, titled "What You Leave Behind", features a montage of scenes from the show's seven seasons, highlighting the evolution of the characters and their relationships.

In not one of the scenes does Jadzia Dax appear — not even in Worf's clips (and he was married to her).

**Why are there no clips of Jadzia whatsoever?**

Was it a creative decision sparked by frustration over actress Terry Farrell's sudden departure after Season 6?  Did it have to do with rights over the footage?

Comment: Heh...  never even realized this. Sad. 

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to a [1999 interview](http://web.archive.org/web/20031006125500/http://www.startrek.com/startrek/view/community/chat/archive/transcript/1372.html) with Ira Steven Behr, it was indeed a matter of rights; they'd wanted to include her in some form, but she wouldn't let them use archive footage and they didn't have the budget to shoot new scenes at her asking price:

> Q: Why weren't any past episodes with Terry Farrell shown on the DS9 finale?
>   Lizzy Liz
>
> ISB: We had planned to see Terry Farrell in the flashbacks but she refused to let us use any of her clips. The way I see it is this: Her manager was informed that we were thinking of using Terry in a scene in the final episode. It would have probably been three hours of work... maybe four. The price they quoted us was too high for the budget. After all, this was a show where we had to cut out hundreds of thousands of dollars from the original draft. Her manager was informed that we weren't going to be able to use Terry. *[...]*  When it came to the issue of the clips, they again felt that they would prefer that we went a different way without using the character of Jadzia Dax.

This is supported by comments made by Ronald D. Moore on his AOL page that same year, as [reported](https://forum.gateworld.net/threads/17650-Deep-Space-9-Superior?s=abea35018ab7745addeed21df2d20f65&p=6677869&viewfull=1#post6677869) by [several](http://www.trektoday.com/archives/june1999_classic.shtml) online [sources](http://www.lcarscom.net/rdm990608.htm):

> **Why was Jadzia excluded from Worf's Memories of DS9? Is there some animosity between Terry Farrel and the ST Execs?**
>
> In order to use a clip of someone from a previous episode, you first have to obtain permission from the actor in question. Usually permission is routinely granted and a nominal fee is paid (unlike writers and directors, who receive a flat fee and don't get the option of saying yes or no). In this case, we were unable to obtain permission. And no, we weren't real happy about it.

Interestingly, Farrell herself suggested [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/4terryfarrell/status/742104039500963840) in 2016 that she *did* give (or would have given) her permission, implying that she wasn't asked directly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> [**@DyloniusFunk**](https://twitter.com/DyloniusFunk/status/742099499867217920) In the finale all the characters did a montage of flashbacks to different moments from past 7 years (1/2)
>
> [**@DyloniusFunk**](https://twitter.com/DyloniusFunk/status/742099668180439042) My dad & i found it funny that for legal reasons Worf couldn't remember any moments with his wife. (2/2).
>
> [**@4TerryFarrel**](https://twitter.com/4terryfarrell/status/742104039500963840) Isnt that crazy. I gave my permission ever time Paramount asked. Someone dropped the ball that episode.

Presumably the DS9 producers never spoke to Farrell directly, only through her agents, and negotiations just didn't work out, or else there was some miscommunication between the studio and the DS9 writers.

Comment: iirc they did get into some trouble in S7 when they showed a photograph of Jadzia and Worf's wedding. That's the only instance of Jadzia being seen in S7

Comment: Seems weird. I would've thought the production/owning company would have perpetual use rights to all their own footage. Interesting.

Comment: @eidylon I was also surprised, so I [posed the question](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/14019/9120) to our good friends at Law.SE